# TPROXY redirect and routing decision

Tags: iptables, transparent-proxy

I would like to ask what happens internally when redirecting using Tproxy.

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 1 --on-port 40001
```

It located in `PREROUTING` in the mangle table of iptables.

As far as I know, the routing decision is made after the `PREROUTING` chain.

When redirecting using Tproxy as above.

Packet through `ip rule` & `routing table`? Or does it go directly to the local 40001 port?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I want to know what happened because I find if I use TPROXY, the routing table looks like not work.

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 887 packets, 200K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  20M 4462M TPROXY_SRV_eth3.1  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain TPROXY_SRV_eth3.1 (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  225 14048 TPROXY     tcp  --  eth3.1 *       0.0.0.0/0            172.168.2.0/24       tcp dpt:8000 TPROXY redirect 172.168.2.3:8000 mark 0x1/0x1
```

The route table with fwmark 1 like

```
local default dev lo scope host
```

The IP rule is

```
0:  from all lookup local
1:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup 1
10: from all fwmark 0x29 lookup 41
10: from all fwmark 0xc lookup test
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

I found the packet does not go through table 1 because I can't capture it by tcpdump.
anyone can help me